# Toggle show/hide of divs in a foreach loop using Jquery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, foreach, toggle, show-hide

Having a bit of an issue with show/hide or toggle with it comes to php foreach loops.

My php look like this:

```
<?php
$keys = $personArray;

foreach($keys as $key){

$key = get_field_object($key);
$key_NAME   = $key['name'];
$key_NAME2  = $key['name2'];
$key_TYPE   = $key['type'];


echo '<div style="display:block;margin-botton:4px;">';
echo '<span id="kname" class="hide">' . $key_NAME . '</span><span id="kname2" class="hide"' . $key_NAME2 . '</span>';
echo ' | ';
echo '<span id="ktype" class="hide">' . $key_TYPE . '</span>';
echo '</div>';

}


//I will get;
/*
JamesJack | Artist
SamMike | Singer
CurtTrisha | Dancer
*/
?>
```

But I need to have jQuery with checkboxes show/hide key_TYPE and toggle between key_NAME and key_NAME2

How can I do this right? My current code only effect the first line of results.

Here is the rest of the code:

```
<style>

.hide{display:none;}

</style>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="changename"){
            $("#kname").toggle();
        }else{
            $("#kname2").toggle();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="hidetype"){
            $("#ktype").toggle();
        }

    });
});
</script>

<html>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="vauChange" value="changename"> Toggle name</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="vauChange" value="hidetitle"> Hide Title</label>
</html>
```

My code isn't working right.

Comment: `id="kname"` - **ALL** of your elements have the same ID, which is illegal. DOM ids must be unique across the document. since they have to be unique, getElementById will only ever return the FIRST matching element it finds, because there couldn't possibly ever be any duplicate ids elsewhere in the same document.

Comment: so what can I do to make each output unique? and if I click the chkbox will all element hide like it should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like using data- attributes for easy access in jquery

```
<?php
$keys = $personArray;

foreach($keys as $key){

$key = get_field_object($key);
$key_NAME   = $key['name'];
$key_NAME2  = $key['name2'];
$key_TYPE   = $key['type'];

echo '<div style="display:block;margin-botton:4px;">';
echo '<span class="hide change-name" data-name1="'.$key_NAME.'" data-name2="'.$key_NAME2.'">'.$key_NAME.'</span>';
echo ' | ';
echo '<span class="hide toggle-title">'.$key_TYPE.'</span>';
echo '</div>';
}
?>

<html>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="vauChange" value="changename" id="toggle-name-box"> Toggle name</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="vauChange" value="hidetitle" id="toggle-title-box"> Hide Title</label>
</html>
<script>
  $('#toggle-name-box').click(function() {
      $('.change-name').each(function() {
          cur = $(this).text();
          $(this).text(cur == $(this).data('name1') ? $(this).data('name2') : $(this).data('name1'));
      });
  });
  $('#toggle-title-box').click(function() {
      $('.toggle-title').each(function() {
          $(this).toggleClass('hide');
      });
  });
</script>
```

And the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f934qL1d/5/

Comment: Thank @DaveK. There seems to be a problem with the example you've provided in jsfiddle. In your example "data-name1"  of one item is not the same as the second item, it has **data-name1="keyname1"** on the first and **data-name1="keyname2"** on the second when they both should be the same, correct?

The list will print out as:
`code /*
James - Artist, 
James - Singer, 
James - Dancer
*/`

I want to change all **James** to **Jack**

Comment: No they need to be different. I'm storing both alternative names in the data attributes to toggle between them. Basically it checks to see if the current text in the span is name1, and if so it changes it to name2, if not, changes it to name1.

I've updated the jsfiddle to reflect your output example.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the same id on all elements.

First of all use class instead of id for your elements

```
echo '<div style="display:block;margin-botton:4px;">';
echo '<span class="kname hide">' . $key_NAME . '</span><span class="kname2 hide"' . $key_NAME2 . '</span>';
echo ' | ';
echo '<span class="ktype hide">' . $key_TYPE . '</span>';
echo '</div>';
```

On the jquery use the DOM to target the elements relatively to the element that fires the event.

So the jquery will be something like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr("value")=="changename"){
        $(this).closest('span.kname').toggle();
    }else{
        $(this).closest('div').find('span.kname2').toggle();
    }
    if($(this).attr("value")=="hidetitle"){
        // same for ktitle since I can't see it in your html
    }

});
```

});

Comment: but will this work on a "foreach" statement. Remember, only one echoed line hides, the others dont even though they have the same id or class name. Also I meant "ktype" and "hidetype"as the value. I've updated that thx.